# “Tenter d'en … ” vs “tenter de”

Tags: pronoms

Why does one write *tenter d'en + infinitive* instead of *tenter de infinitive*?

An example:

> ... notre vénérée profession ne s'intéresse plus aux causes des
>   maladies; elle perd plutôt son temps et ses ressources à **tenter
>   d'en** traiter des symptômes. ([ref](http://www.editions-trecarre.com/code-obesite/jason-fung/livre/9782895687078))

Why not *tenter de traiter*?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a duplicate. The linked question has `en` come after the être verb, instead of it coming after the de preposition as in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of *en* is not related to the use of the verb *tenter (de)*. *Tenter* is used to modify the verb *traiter* and the sentence could have been:

> ... elle perd plutôt son temps et ses ressources à en traiter des symptômes.

What the author wants to say is:

> notre vénérée profession ne s'intéresse plus aux causes **des maladies** ; elle perd plutôt son temps et ses ressources à (tenter de) traiter des symptômes **des maladies**.

Using *en* avoids repeating *des maladies*. It is an indirect object of the verb *traiter* and must be placed before the verb.

*En* is the third person personal pronoun that replaces the noun *maladies* preceded by *des* (*de + les*). The preposition *de* followed by the definite article is used here to introduce a characteristic of the *symptômes* (they're not any symptoms, they're the ones of  the diseases).

Here's a little dialogue with a simpler example of the same use of *en*:
- Comment allons-nous pouvoir rentrer dans la maison ?
- Parce que j'en ai la clé. (= j'ai la clé de la maison).